# Android App can't be installed/updated for some users (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play

Our company is developing Android app in Xamarin.Forms (3.5.0) framework. Since now all users were able to update application from Google Play store without problems. After new update some of them got Google Play error "Can't install app". Like this one https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XOAgJz2vQu4/hqdefault.jpg but without error code. This problem occurs only for some users (about 80% users already updated to newest version). They already tried deleting Google Play cache and other solutions to this problem. We did not change any of min and target SDK. We added/changed:

- Support for 64 bit devices (added `arm64-v8a` in Xamarin build settings so now  APK containts `lib/armeabi-v7a` and new folder `lib/arm64-v8a`)
- added `networkSecurityConfig` to support our self signed SSL certificate
- `launchMode` set to `singleTask`
- add providers `com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider` and `com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider`
- add receiver `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver` with permission `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES`
- add services `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService` and `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService` with permission `android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE`

I don't think the problem is in our application package or in changes we made. For instance one user has this problem with Samsung Note 9 but statistics in Google Play console indicates that updates for this device from version 1.0.1 to version 1.1.1 were successful in 118 devices. The same is with other devices. Like 99% devices are updated successfully but some of them install or update fails.

Can you provide some help and solutions to this problem? We can't even reproduce this error in our devices, because every update or delete & install procedure works without problems. It works on 32 bit devices, it works on 64 bit devices, it works on devices and Android OS versions that users have problems with. We don't get any of error messages or logs becuase error is in Google Play. We get many of 1 star reviews, want to help our users but we just can't...

Thanks!

Comment: I have a very similar issue; the only thing that was changed in my case is the 64-bit support, which is now required by Google Play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Crashlytics integration into Xamarin.Forms application. After reverting all changes made when integrating Crashlytics and releasing new version people can now install and update application successully. To confirm this I created new test application from scratch, added all nuget packages, enabled Crashlytics feature and install on emulator. After that I tried to install our previous application version, which contains Crashlytics. When I try to install with adb I got error:

```
adb: failed to install temp\our.app.package.name.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/our.app.package.name--xtUfCuOL6yxO3kB0Ev4tQ==: 
Can't install because provider name dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket (in package our.app.package.name) is already used by com.companyname.TestApplication]
```

We are going to use App Center crash report system now, becuase integrating is so simple (takes about 20 mins) and without side effects such as this.